# Search string using pdfgrep and format output

Tags: linux, pdf, grep, formatting, output

I'm using pdfgrep to search for a name in multiple pdfs stored in a directory and storing results in a file:

`pdfgrep -R 'My string' > ../output-file`

It prints the following output:

```
./file1.pdf:     91   My String                               Just_another_string                   75              53            49            30              57               48                74             69
./file2.pdf:     8    My String                                Just_another_string                                                              40
./file3.pdf:     92 My String                                  Just_another_string                   64              62            76             50           76            88             80             148
```

I'm getting so many unecessary whitespaces in each line between each column in the output. I'd like to reformat the output such that these multiple white spaces are reduced to just one whitespace between each column.

Is there any way I could do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty way: use awk.  Assuming the format always looks like that:
(assuming your original command was correct)

```
pdfgrep -R 'My string' | awk '{print "$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9"}' > ../output-file
```

Edit based on comments:

@Inian's answer is better (since it handles arbritary numbers of columns), but in a nutshell, what mine is doing is telling awk to split the input by whitespace and then print it back out with a single space between each column ... you could for example skip the first column by not including $1, or swap say the 3rd and 4th columns by printing $4 $3).

For efficiency, if you want to shove this into a database, you probably want to look into using Python (or Perl or PHP but a quick check on my profile should show my preference) to actually do the SQL importing. 500 PDF's doesn't really phase me... I would expect you could get away with something like:

```
pdfgrep -R 'My string' > ../output-file
```

And then run a python program that looks something like:

```
import sys

with open("output-file","rt") as f:
   for line in f:
      data = line.split() #now you have an array split by whitespace
      cleanline = " ".join(data) #now each element has a single space between it and the next
      #or you could just stick data directly into the database; details omitted because there are way too many variables here
```

Comment: (note that there's smarter ways, also that the way above requires you to add $10 $11 ... if you have more columns, and also note that my string will be two columns)

Comment: Is there any optimized way of doing this? I might be passing this values to database to store them and use efficiently later on. To give you an idea I have more than 500 pdfs that I might need searching into. :)

Comment: Also can you please explain what you are doing? I am completely new to awk.

Comment: Inian seem to have deleted his answer. But your answer also serves the purpose for the most part. Thanks!